# Sites not opened in mysite

Tags: mysite

When I click on the "Sites" link (see screenshot) on a Mysite page , it is not opened, instead it redirects to home page newsfeed.

[image][image]

Comment: Reset your IIS and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

the message on the page showing, sharepoint is creating your Mysite. "we are almost ready!" is the message you get 1st time. But if you and all other user getting this error all the time then you have to make sure following things.

- configured My site url correctly in user profile service application
- Created a wild card managed path for My sites
- Given a permission to user to create self-service site on your
  my-site web application.
- Make Sure Self-Service Site Creation enabled on the MySite web app.
- Distributed Cache is up and running.

http://bernado-nguyen-hoan.com/2013/04/10/my-site-creation-stuck-at-were-almost-ready-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: iam checked but its still not working , same page opened